# What is wrong with my odd-even sort routine?

Tags: c, sorting

I'm trying to implement an odd-even sorting routine. I think I have the central idea down but something is incorrect.

```
int odd = 1;
int even = 0;

do {
    for (odd; odd < size-1; odd += 2) {
        if (unsorted[odd] > unsorted[odd + 1])
            swap(&unsorted[odd], &unsorted[odd + 1]);
    }

    for (even; even < size-1; even += 2) {
        if (unsorted[even] > unsorted[even + 1])
            swap(&unsorted[even], &unsorted[even + 1]);
    }
} while (unsorted[odd] > unsorted[odd + 1] && unsorted[even] > unsorted[even +1]);
```

I initially thought my mistake was in the while condition but even when I iterate over the do loop hundreds of thousands of times the unsorted array never becomes sorted. Anyone have any ideas where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: Did you try to use a debugger (like `gdb` if on Linux) to understand what your code is doing??

Comment: Fix your indentation, first - it's making your code much, _much_ harder to read (and might be hiding bugs!)

Answer (score 1):

I think Deepak is right. Moreover, I the condition in while should be false after the first run

```
unsorted[odd] > unsorted[odd + 1] && unsorted[even] > unsorted[even +1]
```

should both be false as you ran through the for loops making sure they don't occur. Your array is never visited again to make future adjustments to the values in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the example in wiki, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odd%E2%80%93even_sort

I think you exiting right after the first do-while loop since the odd & even are already > size and might be undefined.